# Nodejs: Nodist no valid Win32 error

Tags: node.js

After installing nodist (version 1.3.15) and trying to run an older version using the statement:

```
   nodist run v0.6.6
```

I get the following error:

```
   CreateProcessW: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

For your information, I performed the following steps to install nodist:

1. unzip nodist file to c:\nodist
2. execute in cmd: nodist update
3. add path of nodist (c:\nodist) to "user variables"

Anyone suggestions how I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that node-gyp has v0.6.6 as one of its targets. You can check by opening the folder .node-gyp. Each node version it has as a target has its own folder.